# How to shrink div and div elements with the size of window?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

The banner picture shrinks with window size but the header and header items stay the same size. It looks bad when the header takes about 30% of the display in the phone view. This is my CSS -

```
.headerdiv{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100% ;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: rgb(3, 3, 3);
    justify-content: center;
}

  return (
        <div className={styles.headerdiv}>
            <div className={styles.logo} >
                <img src={logo} alt=""/>
            </div>
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <Link className={styles.link} to="/">Home</Link>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <Link className={styles.link} to="/blog">Blog</Link>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <Link className={styles.link} to="/about">About</Link>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <Link className={styles.link} to="/FAQ">FAQ</Link>
                    </li>
                </ul>
             </div>
         </div>
      );
```

Comment: Would you post the relevant section of HTML?

Comment: just the CSS part won't help.

Comment: Try relative css units

Comment: @DanMullin  updated . check now

Comment: @devd added html

Answer (score 0):

I generally swap out a mobile formatted image and use img-srcset to switch the image when it's small or large device.

Here is some documentation:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images

I believe the issue is the image scales but the content/text does not. Compensating for that could lead to a lot of different solutions like using media queries to swap out content or have particular styles for particular sizes.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention banner picture in outside div below the header. But I want it to shrink like the banner as header covers half of the display in phone view.